# Python numpy code optimization with enumeration

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization

I've been trying to optimize this bit of code here but I've never really done optimization like this and I'm not quite sure how to start or how to analyze which part of the code runs slow. I've been really stuck on this and haven't managed to get any further for a while. Any tips or suggestions would be welcome.

```
q = np.array([0]*10 + [1] + [0]*10)
W = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
discreteA = {'Prior': 0.6153846153846154,
             'Prob': np.array([0.0125, 0., 0., 0.0125, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.0375, 0.075, 0.1, 0.2125, 0.1375, 0.15, 0.1, 0.0875, 0.0125, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])}
discreteC = {'Prior': 0.38461538461538464,
             'Prob': np.array([0., 0., 0., 0.02, 0.02, 0.22, 0.46, 0.16, 0.1, 0.02, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])}

float(np.sum([np.dot(W.T[x,:], (discrete_A['Prob'][i]*discrete_A['Prior'], discrete_B['Prob'][i]*discrete_B['Prior'])) for i,x in enumerate(q)]))
```

I am running this code for for q values of `qs = np.array(list(product((0,1), repeat=21)))` to find optimal q and it is orders of magnitude too slow.

Comment: it would probably help if you gave some example data and the desired output

Comment: You don't need the `float`.  It would also be easier to read if you replaced the `dict` with separate variables.  A code line that requires scrolling is harder to read.  Make the calculation clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached some code below doing some basic optimisation of snippet of code you provided. It's roughly a 7 times faster; not quite the orders of magnitude you were looking for but hopefully it gives you some ideas.

Note the code you provided didn't work as you used undefined `discrete_A` `discrete_B` but I assumed these should be the `discreteA` and `discreteC` you defined above.

There are a couple principles:

- When working with numpy if you can do a vector operation on an array it usually faster than indexing into the array and performing the calculation in python. numpy is a C library and calculation within the library will benefit from compile time optimisations. Performing operations on arrays also benefits from processor predictive caching (your CPU expects you to use adjacent memory looking forward and preloads it; you potentially lose this benefit if you access the data piecemeal).
- Avoid doing things multiple times when you don't need to by caching intermediate results. A good example of this is the matrix transpose were you were doing the same operation 20 times when you only needed to do it once.

It's sounds like probably have some scope in the code which is calling into this to apply these principles as well. If you are calling into this code a lot it may well be worth caching at a higher level, and potentially looking at caching operations with larger chunks of data. I'm not sure what your `product` method is so I can't really comment.

That aside, it's well worth getting familiar with the profilers in python [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers). Profilers are key to understand what is taking time in your code.

The improvements steps in the following code are (time in seconds):

```
Results match.
v1: 9.979970299871638
v2: 8.393995099933818
v3: 7.255605699960142
v4: 7.535984199959785
v5: 6.710812199860811
v6: 1.4270518000703305
```

Code changes:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

q = np.array([0]*10 + [1] + [0]*10)
W = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
discreteA = {'Prior': 0.6153846153846154,
             'Prob': np.array([0.0125, 0., 0., 0.0125, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.0375, 0.075, 0.1, 0.2125, 0.1375, 0.15, 0.1, 0.0875, 0.0125, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])}
discreteC = {'Prior': 0.38461538461538464,
             'Prob': np.array([0., 0., 0., 0.02, 0.02, 0.22, 0.46, 0.16, 0.1, 0.02, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])}

def v1():
    return float(np.sum([np.dot(W.T[x,:], (discreteA['Prob'][i]*discreteA['Prior'], discreteC['Prob'][i]*discreteC['Prior'])) for i,x in enumerate(q)]))

# instead of doing the Prob * Prior calculation one at a time on each loop, do it as a vector operation
# first, then index into the resultant vector. The vector multiply is faster as it happens in C without
# having to come back to python
def v2():
    prodA = discreteA['Prob'] * discreteA['Prior']
    prodC = discreteC['Prob'] * discreteC['Prior']
    return float(np.sum([np.dot(W.T[x,:], (prodA[i], prodC[i])) for i,x in enumerate(q)]))

# there are only two possible transposed matrices so don't recalulate every time
def v3():
    prodA = discreteA['Prob'] * discreteA['Prior']
    prodC = discreteC['Prob'] * discreteC['Prior']
    trans = (W.T[0,:], W.T[1,:])
    return float(np.sum([np.dot(trans[x], (prodA[i], prodC[i])) for i,x in enumerate(q)]))

# there's no need to enumerate, you can just index directly into q
def v4():
    prodA = discreteA['Prob'] * discreteA['Prior']
    prodC = discreteC['Prob'] * discreteC['Prior']
    trans = (W.T[0,:], W.T[1,:])
    return np.sum([np.dot(trans[q[i]], (prodA[i], prodC[i])) for i in range(len(q))])

# sum from a generator rather than creating a list. note np.sum(generator) is depreciated and np.sum(np.fromiter(generator)) or built-in sum is preferred
# note this changes result from 0.5153846153846154 to 0.5153846153846153 due to differences in python and numpy sum
def v5():
    prodA = discreteA['Prob'] * discreteA['Prior']
    prodC = discreteC['Prob'] * discreteC['Prior']
    trans = (W.T[0,:], W.T[1,:])
    return sum((np.dot(trans[q[i]], (prodA[i], prodC[i])) for i in range(len(q))))

# do the dot product calculation manually as vector operation
# rather than doing it iteratively calling np.dot
def v6():
    not_q = np.where(q == 1, 0, 1)
    prodA = discreteA['Prob'] * discreteA['Prior']
    prodC = discreteC['Prob'] * discreteC['Prior']
    dots = (q * prodA) + (not_q * prodC)
    return np.sum(dots)

if (res := v1()) == v2() and res == v3() and res == v4() and abs(res - v5()) < 0.000000000000001 and (res == v6()):
    print(f'Results match.')

print(f'v1: {timeit.timeit(v1, number=100000)}')
print(f'v2: {timeit.timeit(v2, number=100000)}')
print(f'v3: {timeit.timeit(v3, number=100000)}')
print(f'v4: {timeit.timeit(v4, number=100000)}')
print(f'v5: {timeit.timeit(v5, number=100000)}')
print(f'v6: {timeit.timeit(v6, number=100000)}')
```